# Rspec shared context and factory parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a lot of specs that need to have authentication contexts.
I want to DRY specs and I've created a shared context.
And I need to passa some parameters to the shared context but I can't.

example:

```
RSpec.describe "Letters", type: :request do
  let(:key)        { %i(a b c d) }

  describe "GET /" do
     context "authentication" do
        it_behaves_like "authentication token", key
     end
  end
```

But when I run the spec the following error occurs:

> `key` is not available on an example group (e.g. a `describe` or
>   `context` block). It is only available from within individual examples
>   (e.g. `it` blocks) or from constructs that run in the scope of an
>   example (e.g. `before`, `let`, etc).

How can I solve that ?
Thanks.

Comment: The answer is in the docs: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/example-groups/shared-example-group#passing-parameters-to-a-shared-example-group

Comment: Don't use `let`. Pass array literal directly in this case.

Comment: I've posted some example code but I can't just pass the array. There is a logic that has to be followed.

Comment: @gui12344455 can't the logic be moved to the shared context?

Comment: no, there are other contexts that uses the logic